# sphinx search data files

Tags: sphinx

below is sphinx's data directory, is it safe to delete the .tmp files after indexing?  will searchd use them?

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    24M Apr 27 21:34 myindex.spa
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   929M Apr 27 21:35 myindex.spd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    409 Apr 27 21:35 myindex.sph
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    50M Apr 27 21:35 myindex.spi
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      0 Apr 27 21:34 myindex.spk
-rw------- 1 root   root      0 May  2 08:57 myindex.spl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      0 Apr 27 21:33 myindex.spm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   782M Apr 27 21:35 myindex.spp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    17M Apr 27 21:35 myindex.sps
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   2.9G May  2 04:09 myindex.tmp.spa
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    82G May  2 13:03 myindex.tmp.spd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   949M May  2 13:02 myindex.tmp.spi
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      0 May  2 04:09 myindex.tmp.spk
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      0 Apr 30 11:33 myindex.tmp.spl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      0 May  2 04:07 myindex.tmp.spm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   106G May  2 13:03 myindex.tmp.spp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   2.1G May  2 04:07 myindex.tmp.sps
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      0 Apr 30 11:34 myindex.tmp.tmp0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   247G May  2 04:07 myindex.tmp.tmp1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   2.8G May  2 04:07 myindex.tmp.tmp2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      0 May  2 04:09 myindex.tmp.tmp8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the .tmp files are created while you're indexing with the `--rotate` option defined. If you look at the timestamp on them you can see they're newer than the current indexes being used.

Once the rotate has completed the `tmp` files will replace the existing ones and the existing ones deleted.